# How to tag a textarea as "Required" on option selection

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, selection, required

I am writing an .html page which is to be used to perform a system checkout and verify functionality of various aspects of that system. The .html page features a table encapsulated in a form with each row of that table being a step to verify an aspect of the system (e.g. Step 1: Do something) while each column is different criteria for that checkout process (e.g. Step #, Step Instruction, Expected Result, Actual Result, and Comments).

For the Actual Result column, I have a selection for blank (Incomplete), Pass, Fail, and N/A. The Comments column features a disabled textarea box with a placeholder reading "No Comments".

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th align="center"><strong>Step</strong></th>
                <th align="left"><strong>Instruction</strong></th>
                <th align="left"><strong>Expected Result</strong></th>
                <th align="left"><strong>Actual Result</strong></th>
                <th align="left"><strong>Comments</strong></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top">1.</td>
            <td align="left" valign="top">Do something.</td>
            <td align="left" valign="top">Something happens.</td>
            <td align="center" valign="top"><select id="testResult" name="testResult">
                    <option value="Incomplete" selected></option>
                    <option value="Pass">Pass</option>
                    <option value="Fail">Fail</option>
                    <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td align="center" valign="top"><textarea rows="4" cols="25" id="userComments" name="userComments" placeholder="No comments" disabled="disabled"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top">2.</td>
            <td align="left" valign="top">Do something else.</td>
            <td align="left" valign="top">Something else happens.</td>
            <td align="center" valign="top"><select id="testResult" name="testResult">
                    <option value="Incomplete" selected></option>
                    <option value="Pass">Pass</option>
                    <option value="Fail">Fail</option>
                    <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td align="center" valign="top"><textarea rows="4" cols="25" id="userComments" name="userComments" placeholder="No comments" disabled="disabled"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="systemCheckout" name="systemCheckout">
</form>
```

Through JavaScript, I would like to set the textarea box in the "Comments" column to enabled and to be required should a "Fail" or "N/A" be selected in the preceding "Actual Results" column.

How would I scale this to support numerous rows each featuring a selection and textarea with similar functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code can help you.

```js
let trc = document.getElementsByClassName("testResultClass")
for(let i = 0;i < trc.length;i++) {
  let elem = trc[i]
  elem.onchange = (e) => {
    let txbx = elem.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("testResultBoxClass")[0]
    if(elem.value == "Fail" || elem.value == "N/A"){
      txbx.disabled = false
      txbx.required = true
    } else
      txbx.disabled = true
      txbx.required = false
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th align="center"><strong>Step</strong></th>
                <th align="left"><strong>Instruction</strong></th>
                <th align="left"><strong>Expected Result</strong></th>
                <th align="left"><strong>Actual Result</strong></th>
                <th align="left"><strong>Comments</strong></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top">1.</td>
            <td align="left" valign="top">Do something.</td>
            <td align="left" valign="top">Something happens.</td>
            <td align="center" valign="top"><select id="testResult" name="testResult" class="testResultClass">
                    <option value="Incomplete" selected></option>
                    <option value="Pass">Pass</option>
                    <option value="Fail">Fail</option>
                    <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td align="center" valign="top"><textarea rows="4" cols="25" id="userComments" name="userComments" class="testResultBoxClass" placeholder="No comments" disabled="disabled"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top">2.</td>
            <td align="left" valign="top">Do something else.</td>
            <td align="left" valign="top">Something else happens.</td>
            <td align="center" valign="top"><select id="testResult" name="testResult" class="testResultClass">
                    <option value="Incomplete" selected></option>
                    <option value="Pass">Pass</option>
                    <option value="Fail">Fail</option>
                    <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td align="center" valign="top"><textarea rows="4" cols="25" id="userComments" name="userComments" class="testResultBoxClass" placeholder="No comments" disabled="disabled"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="systemCheckout" name="systemCheckout">
</form>
```

Comment: This does exactly what I want it to do when running the code snippet here, but when I place this code into my website's <script> header, as well as defining the testResultClass and testResultBoxClass classes in the .html itself, nothing occurs when selecting Fail/N/A. I've tried testing this on exterior javascript testing sites as well and get the same result. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @NickJennings you must place the script tag at the end of body tag. This ensure your html was full loaded and all elements exists. If you are adding new elements dynamically, you need to encapsule the binding inside a function and call it after each new row.

Comment: Thank you so much, that did it!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this code.

```js
function checkComment()
{
  var select = document.getElementById('testResult').options[document.getElementById('testResult').selectedIndex].text
  var comment = document.getElementById("userComments");
  if(select === "Fail" || select === "N/A") 
  {
    comment.disabled = false;
  } else {
      comment.value = "";
      comment.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="">
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th align="center"><strong>Step</strong></th>
        <th align="left"><strong>Instruction</strong></th>
        <th align="left"><strong>Expected Result</strong></th>
        <th align="left"><strong>Actual Result</strong></th>
        <th align="left"><strong>Comments</strong></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">1.</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">Do something.</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">Something happens.</td>
        <td align="center" valign="top">
        <select id="testResult" name="testResult" onChange="checkComment()">
            <option value="Incomplete" selected></option>
            <option value="Pass">Pass</option>
            <option value="Fail">Fail</option>
            <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td align="center" valign="top"><textarea rows="4" cols="25" id="userComments" name="userComments" placeholder="No comments" disabled="disabled"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="systemCheckout" name="systemCheckout">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This is working, but only for the first row of the table. As I increment rows (steps) beyond 1, the selections do not enable the textarea boxes beyond the first row. Would an array be required to address this as the table scales?

Comment: No, the circumstances of where these checkouts will be performed is dynamic in that some locations will not have internet access so it will have to run off a locally hosted apache server. I do not believe we can host a jQuery library nor access a CDN.